# How to display dynamic tables in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, json, dynamic-tables

I was trying to make a dynamic table that depending how the JSON is made it loads all the data accordingly. So far I have this:

HTML responsible for creating the table:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="QuotationsController as vm">
<h2>Quotations</h2>
<p>
    <a href="\">Create Quotation</a>
</p>   
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="Quotation in vm.Quotations">
        <th ng-repeat="(key,val) in Quotation"> {{ key }} </th>             
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="Quotation in vm.Quotations">
        <td ng-repeat="(key,val) in Quotation"> {{ val }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="\">Edit</a> |
            <a href="\">Details</a> |
            <a href="\">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular
    .module("PPM")
    .controller("QuotationsController", ["QuotationsService", QuotationsController]);    

function QuotationsController(QuotationsService) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.Quotations = [
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Description": "Leaf Rake",
        "Name": "GDN-0011",            
    },
    {
        "ID" : 2,
        "Description": "Garden Cart",
        "Name": "GDN-0023",            
    },
     {
         "ID": 5,
         "Description": "Hammer",
         "Name": "TBX-0048",             
     },
     {
         "ID": 8,
         "Description": "Saw",
         "Name": "TBX-0022",             
     },
     {
         "ID": 10,
         "Description": "Video Game Controller",
         "Name": "GMG-0042",             
     }
    ];        
}
```

})();

(I have hard-coded the data in the controller for testing purposes only. I will later delete this and make calls to a Web API.)

This gives me the following result:

[image]

I don't want the table headers to be repeated for each Quotation that exists. I just want to display it once, but I don't know how to acess the properties without ng-repeat. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either have your controller loop through the first result or have the html do it. Either way.

Html way

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="QuotationsController as vm">
<h2>Quotations</h2>
 <p> 
    <a href="\">Create Quotation</a>
 </p>
 <table class="table">
     <tr >
        <th ng-repeat="(key,val) in vm.Quotations[0] "> 
          {{ key }}
        </th> 
     </tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="Quotation in vm.Quotations"> 
        <td ng-repeat="(key,val) in Quotation">
           {{ val }}
        </td> 
        <td>
            <a href="\">Edit</a> | <a href="\">Details</a> | <a href="\">Delete</a> 
        </td> 
     </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple headers because you used ng-repeat on `<tr>` element containing `<th>` elements. Remove ng-repeat.

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="(key,val) in vm.Quotation[0]"> {{ key }} </th>             
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="Quotation in vm.Quotations">
        <td ng-repeat="(key,val) in Quotation"> {{ val }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="\">Edit</a> |
            <a href="\">Details</a> |
            <a href="\">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Something like that should work.

You probably would like to add ng-if in case there is 0 elements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!